# Dried+, Dired-K. Available space in KB/MB?

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+, Dired-K

Here my dired buffer:

[image: dired]

As you can see `Dired-K` show size of files and folder in **KB/MB**. OK. Nice.

But total available is show in **bytes**. Is it possible to show availabe space also in **KB/MB**?

Answer (score 1):

1. The sizes shown in the listing as `2k` etc. are available using appropriate `ls` switches (e.g., **`-h`**, for "human-readable"). I don't know whether Dired-K imposes such a switch, but in any case you don't need Dired-K or Dired+ for that.
2. That `total available` display comes from vanilla Dired. And no, currently there is no other way to show the value than what you see. That's the answer to your question.
3. Libraries [`ls-lisp+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ls-lisp%2b.el) and [`files+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/files%2b.el) enhance that total-available line by adding the number of files for the current listing (e.g. of a subdir) and the total number of files listed in the Dired buffer. If you use them you'll see something like this, instead of what you show. (If you hit `RET` or click the mouse on the text then `*Help*` pops up with complete info about the directory.)

   ```
   files 1142/1142 space used 66944 available 91321548
   ```
4. Dired+ is not involved in this, but the  [`ls-lisp+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ls-lisp%2b.el) and [`files+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/files%2b.el) enhancement is described on the [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#secondHeaderLine) page.